# Selfcalling anonymus function with requestAntimationFrame

Tags: typescript

I wrote a simple 2D-tile-renderer in Javascript an converted it the other day to typescript.

Everything went fine, the only difficulty I had was calling the window.requestAnimationFrame with an callback.

I managed it to get it run correctly, but it looks not the typescript way:

```
        // ... some initzialitaion Code above

        var mapper = this;
        (function animloop() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
            mapper.draw();
        })();
```

I had to stuff the "this" into an auxillary variable to avoid the use of this in the anonymous function.

I tired to use a type-script lambda ( => ), but struggled with the parameter I have to give into the requestAnimationFrame method.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
let animloop = () => 
{
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animloop);
    this.draw();
}

animloop();
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. I wonder why I did not find this by myself :)